# Understanding Quaternion equivalence to matrix transform

Tags: quaternions, affinetransform

A quaternion is obviously equivalent to a rotation matrix, but a 4x4 matrix does more than just rotation. It also does translation and scaling.

A matrix for affine transforms can actually be represented with 12 elements because the last row is constant:

```
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
0 0 0 1


x' = a*x + b*y + c*z + d
y' = e*x + f*y + g*z + h
z' = i*x + j*y + k*z + l
```

A full transform therefore takes 9 multiplies and 9 adds.
For the three affine transforms: rotation, scale, and translation I would like to know if a quaternion-based system is competitive.  I have looked all over and have not found one anywhere.

Given a quaternion p = (w,x,y,z)
For rotation, q' = pqp'.  I could add a translation vector: t=(tx,ty,tz)

q' = pqp' + t

That is just 7 elements as compared to 12 with matrices, though it is slightly more operations. 
That still does not support scaling though.  Is there a complete equivalent?

Note: If the only answer is to convert the rotation to a matrix, then that is not really an answer.  The question is whether a quaternion system can perform affine transform without matrices.

If there is an equivalence, can anyone point me to a java or c++ class so I can see how this works?

Comment: " The question is whether a quaternion system can perform affine transform without matrices."

You can use pair Q + T  quaternion and translation vector and apply 

Pt  =  qPq' + t 

Pt - transformed point 
P- original point